# Redirect if email matches using php

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I am trying to process a form where if a user enters an email that exists in a database they are redirected to the index page but I can't seem to find out why my code isn't working. It doesn't make it to the if statement to check the user.

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database, $port);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connection Successful";

$query = "SELECT * FROM FacultyRegistration where email = " . $_POST['email'] ;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ("There was an error:" . mysqli_error($conn));

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
    else{
        header('Location: register.php');
        exit();
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: try to `echo mysqli_num_rows($result)` to check the value return.

Comment: I get this error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@BUTLER.EDU' at line 1"

Comment: try `$query = "SELECT * FROM FacultyRegistration where email = '" . $_POST['email']."'" ;`

Comment: @Ben Escape your input.. with `mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["email"])`

Comment: @C0dekid.php where should I add that line?

Comment: @Ben Replace this line `$query = "SELECT * FROM FacultyRegistration where email = " . $_POST['email'] ;` with this line of code `$query = "SELECT * FROM FacultyRegistration WHERE email = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) . "'";`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$email = addslashes($_POST['email']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM FacultyRegistration where email = '$email'" ;
```

You didn't put the email between quotations.

Comment: Do you have any quotation or special characters except `@` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this code

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
```

to

```
if (count($result) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you send content before sending headers. 
If you need to use header() function then you need to be sure that no content was returned to browser.

Probably, You get `Headers already sent` warning.

To make it work remove this line

```
echo "Connection Successful";
```

and also change your query to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `FacultyRegistration` WHERE `email` = '" . $_POST['email'] . "';";
```

You get SQL error because `@` is special character and you need to escape email with string literal `''`

It would be nice also to add some escaping or prepared statement to avoid SQL injection for example [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)